# How to run long-running background process without killing by os?

Tags: android, background, android-service

I have a task to implement the background process to receive and parse SMS. Using several tutorials I did it, but after some time (1 - 1.5 mins) this process is destroying by os. Definitely, it's normal behavior because of background limitations, my question is: "How to make this process really long-running?" My simplify code:

1. Run background process:

```
    Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Intent mService = new Intent(context, ServiceCommunicator.class);
    context.startService(mService);
```

2. ServiceCommunicator.java

```
public class ServiceCommunicator extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "cordova-plugin-sms-receive";
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    
    private SMSReceiver mSMSReceiver;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "service onCreate");
     
        // Start worker in own thread
        Thread worker = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                mSMSReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
                mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                mIntentFilter.addAction(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
                ServiceCommunicator.this.registerReceiver(mSMSReceiver, mIntentFilter);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "register receiver");
            }
        };
        worker.run();
    }
         
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "service onDestroy");

        // Unregister the SMS receiver
        this.unregisterReceiver(mSMSReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need foreground service

Comment: @Selvin, foreground service needs to push notification and user can cancel it. I need a fully independent process!

Comment: not "push notification" ... just "notification" ... user should have choice so where is the problem? You cann't do something against user will